# Invitation to the Saas platform with payment

Tags: interaction-design, workflow, user-journey

I am looking for some examples of companies/ websites who are using the model below:

1. The company A is using the Saas platform for the assesment (paying for it).
2. The company A wants to invite other companies (supplier B, C, D) to the platform to be assessed (they need to pay as well).

I am interested how the payment is communicated to suppliers B, C, D (other companies).
Currently I am working on the customer journey, where this information is communicated, but not that straight forward (smaller font, at the bottom of the page), which bring friction later in the process, where we ask them to pay.

Do you know any examples?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello @MikeLikePike, and welcome to UX.SE. Instead of asking about examples, I'd suggest that you might be able to get better responses by explaining the challenge you're dealing with and what your goals are. What "assessment" are you talking about? In what way is Company A different from B, C, and D, if they're all paying for the product? Are they using the product in a different capacity? Feel free to [edit] any other details you feel may be relevant into your question.

Comment: Any mocks you have also help give more context to the problem, and show the community some of your efforts, and any constraints you're working with as well

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do a little bit of research on two platforms that I am familiar with that has a platform for doing certification for businesses, [B Corp](https://bcorporation.com.au/) and [Good on You](https://partnerships.goodonyou.eco/) but it might be a bit different from the type of service that you are looking to provide.

What I have found in looking at a few of the businesses in their directory is that in most cases, the business website will use an approved certification asset that usually takes them to the certification website without doing any selling of the platform. I think this is important because the value of the service or product needs to be demonstrated before you can provide the pricing detail, at least in the context of these two certification services that I have looked at.

Unless you have some affiliate or association with the company, I think it can be a bit of a risk not to simply link to the main organization and let them deal with the communication side of things. But I am interested in more details that might help me to understand why you want to do this.